# Select all the TR TD elements in a table if a TR TH element contains some specific text

Tags: jquery

I'm trying the use jquery to select all the TR TD elements in a table if a TR TH element in the same table contains some specific text. I would then like to iterate through all the TR TD elements with each. I've tried lots of approaches without success. I've got multiple tables within the document that have different th elements but are otherwise identical.

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>header1</th>
<tr><td>data1</td><tr>
<tr><td>data2</td><tr>
<tr><td>data3</td><tr>
```

In this case select all the tr td elements if th = header1

Comment: You are missing a `</tr>`. Also, your example is too minimal I think. I doubt all your tables will have only one column

Comment: Show us what you've tried.  That's a must when asking questions on SO.

Comment: I've just updated with a jsfiddle example

http://jsfiddle.net/wGPJ8/4/

Answer (score 0):

If it's only a one dimention why you don't do that :

[EDITED CODE]

```
var td_selection = null ;
var th_to_check = $('tbody tr th') ;
if(th_to_check.text() == 'header1') {
     td_selection = th_to_check.children() ;
}
```

?

But I think the best option is to play with classes. Set a classes to desired td and then select them with

```
td_selection = $('.td_class') ;
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention there are multiple <th> values (multi-dimensional).

I managed the get the if working using

if( $('table tr th').text().slice(0,7) == 'header1') 

since the selector returns all headers but I know its the first one I'm looking for.

The second selector selects all the td elements in the document and not just the elements that belong to the table that contains the header1 th

Comment: For the first problem identify which th you need (ou can use [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) for that. For the second problem I change the code above to match your description, i use [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/).

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think there's something obvious I must be missing. I've pasted an example below to help. I expecting here to show up in the console and I would then like to loop through the td elements where header == header1

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle project to highlight the problem